# TypeScript generic class does not give expected type error

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm experimenting with generic classes in TypeScript and for some reason, I can't produce the type error I'd like to produce when the wrong argument is passed to a function.
There are a few variants I tried but none of them works as long as I use objects as generic type arguments. It only works for basic types like string and boolean.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuAeWA+aBvAUNf0AZgK4B2wAjABQD6A9kgBbwBOAXHIqhgJTQcA3OgEsAJtgC+eAiXIAmWg2bs4fQSPFYpBImWABmFAFVo8AB5J4pUTATI06dIqasORtdCFjJ0-LOAALMamFlY2cE70Liru-J4aPlI4APTJ0ADCAEqwAAo4oJAwAIIhlta2XChFmFr54FDQAEKlYRX2jTVJqdAA7sJMdMRIGdk5ADTQdABGAFbwwMNIAJ4ADvB1hdAA4j4FDQAaLeWc9ludOClpfQNDI7kTU5DCwNDLaxsNAJpH4XaoU3Q6CB4GBSOd8nRSMhoGBoABeaCkeA9aBFKg8ADcEKhwym8MRyKa6KxwEh0LM+KRKP2xOx0KWlMJn1pl0RdFeq3gphYLDoLBgyngADpeowlgB+HBgIX+ahTTEwmV6BTyjGK-z6Kiq9V6AJazFSpXkahmBXS-wKU1q816TVWnXkPVWi7dMAgEBEQYsaCMMACLlvLmsXn8mEwcxrBbwUSG2VUJZmo3ABQJ61JzWph2BeOYoA)

```js
class Test<T> {
    func1(_other: Test<T>) : void {}
    func2(_other: T) : void {}
    func3<U extends Test<T>>(_other: U) : void {}
    func4<U extends T>(_other: U) : void {}
}

// CRTP
class A extends Test<A> {}
class B extends Test<B> {}

// without CRTP, object type
class G {}
class X extends Test<G> {}

// without CRTP, basic type
class Y extends Test<boolean> {}

const a = new A();
const b = new B();
const x = new X();
const y = new Y();

// no type errors here. why?
a.func1(b); a.func2(b); a.func3(b); a.func4(b);
a.func1(x); a.func2(x); a.func3(x); a.func4(x);

// all four have type errors as expected
a.func1(y); a.func2(y); a.func3(y); a.func4(y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is structural, not nominal.

This means that if the the type has the same shape, *then it is the same type*. The name or "instance" of the type doesn't matter.

So these two types are the same:

```
class A extends Test<A> {}
class B extends Test<B> {}
const a: A = new B() // no error
```

But if your classes have different shapes, then the errors you expect pop up:

```
class A extends Test<A> { a = 'string' }
class B extends Test<B> { b = 123 }
const a: A = new B() // type error
// Property 'a' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'A'.(2741)
```

And now, all your examples are errors.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuAeWA+aBvAUNf0AZgK4B2wAjABQD6A9kgBbwBOAXHIqhgJTQcA3OgEsAJtgC+eAiXIAmWg2bs4fQSPFYpBImWABmFAFVo8AB5J4pUTATI06dIqasORtdCFjJ0-LOAALMamFlY2cE70Liru-J4aPlI4APTJ0ADCAEqwAAo4oJAwAIIhlta2XChFmFjQYNAAvNAA5MgswqQA5s3QUgVQ0ABCpWEV9oM10ABGjdAUcvq9OClpAO7CTHTESBnZOQA00HRTAFbwwDtIAJ4ADvD54AMA4tjQnbPN3Uv9MAAaI+VOPYnpMzLMkCxiPAlitoOtNttdrlDlNIMJgNBrncHoVoABNAHhOyoKZ0OggeBgUiTK6zWpUgDyp3OSA4EKhvRhwDopGQdVmpHgq2gRSoPAA3PkeXyZk1BcLBmLJdzeTswXKhdBfkqparoLSNcK8TrYaQ6JjbtDWCw6CwYMp4AA6OGMK4AfhwYEd-moUwldW9egUfvFAf8+ioIbDegCkYlnsD5GoZn9Xv8ChTobTegjmej5FjmeWqTqIBARC2LGgjDAAmhWKtLBtdrqMHMdwu8FECZ9VCuqcTwAU-azg4jI-zgT7EqAA)

So as soon as you start putting properties in those classes, the errors will show up.

Comment: I'm new to TypeScript and that's a fundamental property that hasn't been mentioned in any of the tutorials and guides I've seen so far. Thanks a lot!